# is there another way of doing this?

Tags: python-3.x

Use a while loop to keep prompting a user for a number to use in the following calculation (user_val *77 + (90+2-9+3)). Calculate this answer in a function call random_calculation().
The message to ask for a number should be: "Please enter a number: "
Call the function and print the answer on the screen to the user.
End the program if the user enters "0".
Assume the conditions are checking against an integer. I.e the input must be converted to an integer.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) as well as [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to create a [mre] of ***your own*** attempt. and how to [edit] your questions to improve them.